# Could gerrit submit type inherit from parent project?

Tags: gerrit

I am wondering if the submit type could inherit from its parent project?

Since I have many projects belonging to one parent project. I then only have to change parent project setting, then all the sub-projects inherit parent project setting.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately it's not possible to set "INHERIT" to the "Submit Type" option. You need to choose one of the supported options: Fast_Forward_Only, Merge_If_Necessary, Rebase_If_Necessary, Merge_Always and Cherry_Pick.

Answer (score 1):

While you might not be able to inherit the submit type, it is possible to set default submit type for a set of projects by setting the `repository` section of `gerrit.config` with a wildcard:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#repository